# ng-repeat inside ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind-html

If I have a div as follows

```
<div ng-bind-html="myHtml"></div>
```

and myHtml is defined as follows

```
$scope.names = ['A','B','C'];
$scope.myHtml = "<p ng-repeat=\"name in names\" ng-bind=\"name\"></p>";
```

Why ng-repeat is not processing in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can to use [bind-html-compile](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile) directive instead `bind-html`

[ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) we use for HTML without angular directives like `ng-repeat` or `ng-model` but single DOM

---

Angular should know about new changes and enter them to digest cycle. For that reason we need merge `ngBindHtml` with [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). This is a purpose of `bind-html-compile` directive that should do both things in one.